# Восстанавливать покупки при запуске приложения

Tags: android

Есть такой код, который реализовывает покупку контента (для отключения рекламы) и проверяет была ли совершена покупка. Как в MainActivity при открытии приложения восстанавливать покупки?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.prefs_content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

        BillingProcessor bp;
        Preference preferencepurchase;

        AlertDialog dialog;

        //You can change this setting if you would like to disable rate-my-app
        boolean HIDE_RATE_MY_APP = false;

        private static String PRODUCT_ID_BOUGHT = "item_1_bought";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

            preferencepurchase = findPreference("purchase");
            String license = getResources().getString(R.string.google_play_license);
            if (null != license && !license.equals("")) {
                bp = new BillingProcessor(getActivity(), license, this);
                bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();

                preferencepurchase.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                        bp.purchase(getActivity(), PRODUCT_ID());
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                if (getIsPurchased(getActivity())){
                    preferencepurchase.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_action_done);
                }
            } else {
                PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("preferenceScreen");
                PreferenceCategory billing = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("billing");
                preferenceScreen.removePreference(billing);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingInitialized() {
        /*
         * Called when BillingProcessor was initialized and it's ready to
         * purchase
         */
        }

        @Override
        public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
            if (productId.equals(PRODUCT_ID())){
                setIsPurchased(true, getActivity());
                preferencepurchase.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_action_done);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.settings_purchase_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Log.v("INFO", "Purchase purchased");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.settings_purchase_fail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v("INFO", "Error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
            if (bp.isPurchased(PRODUCT_ID())){
                setIsPurchased(true, getActivity());
                Log.v("INFO", "Purchase actually restored");
                preferencepurchase.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_action_done);
                if (dialog != null) dialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.settings_restore_purchase_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Log.v("INFO", "Purchase restored called");
        }

        public void setIsPurchased(boolean purchased, Context c) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();

            editor.putBoolean(PRODUCT_ID_BOUGHT, purchased);
            editor.apply();
        }

        public static boolean getIsPurchased(Context c) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);

            boolean prefson = prefs.getBoolean(PRODUCT_ID_BOUGHT, false);

            return prefson;
        }

        private String PRODUCT_ID() {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.product_id);
        }

        public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
            bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (bp != null)
                bp.release();

            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, третий день не могу разобраться

Comment: что значит восстановить? вы хотите продавать один и тот же item ? Вам не отвечают потому что скорей всего вопрос не очень точно задан. Вы используете либу, и вполне возможно там нет метода, restore. Хотя я сомневаюсь, но всё можно решить. Это довольно простая операция.

Comment: Этот кусок кода взят с сайта Fandroid из одного из курсов. И я пока плохо в нем разобралась, хотя покупки получается совершить. Хотелось бы чтобы более опытные пользователи посмотрели данный код и подсказали где что можно улучшить и исправить если такие правки необходимы.